# What is this swiveling panel retention device called?

Tags: identify-a-tool

This is something where you put a screw in it, then you turn it and it holds in place a panel or something that is not nailed down.  I'm trying to buy more of them but I can't think of what to call them so that I can look for them.

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, a thing which is mounted in place to do a job indefinitely is not a "tool".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are called plastic screen clips. See picture below from Amazon. They come in a varity of sizes,

[image]

Comment: Mirror clips are a similar-but-different product which might or might not be appropriate for your particular project.

Answer (score 3):

They are also called **latches** but that does depend on your location.

Comment: more specifically turn latch https://www.mcmaster.com/1512N11/